# Proving that the probability of meeting someone k times around n locations, is $P_n^k={1\over k!}{\sum_{m=0}^{n-k} {(-1)^m\over m!}}$

Tags: probability

To be more specific on the question: Two people go around n locations on a random path, say $A, B, C...$, with steps between locations being the same in terms of time. That is that when, for example, person one is at $A$ and person two is at $C$, they will leave their locations simultaneously and arrive at new random locations, so person $1$ might arrive at $F$ while person $2$ would arrive at $D$. Furthermore, one cannot be in the same place twice. Now the question is what is the probability that person $1$ and $2$ will be in the same place k times when they travel though their $n$ locations?

I solved this problem deductively by looking at tree diagrams of $n=2$ to $n=5$ ($n=5$ has already $120$ different possibility outcomes (well, $n$ has $n!$ possibilities)) and looking at all the chains where one meets $0, 1, 2...$ times (so for example for $n=5$,  the number of chains where person 1 and 2 do meet only once is $45$, thus the probability of two people when they travel through $5$ locations is $45/120=37.5%$. Then I set up a table for these numbers for each $n$. From those I tried to come up with a algorithm to generate numbers that are associated with higher n values. I then created a algorithm/equation for generating $n=N+1$ tables from $N$ and $N-1$ tables. Thus I then generated tables up till $n=10$. From those I looked at relations between the probabilities for different $n$ and $k$ ($k$ is the number of times the two people meet). I noticed that the numbers converge to a constant for each $k$ as $n$ goes to infinity. After a bit of thinking it turned out to be:

$$P_{\infty}^k={1\over k!}{1\over e}$$

After even further thought I looked at the series expansion of ${1\over e}$ and it fit perfect with the numbers, thus I managed to get a equation of the probability as a function of both n and k:

$$P_n^k={1\over k!}{\sum_{m=0}^{n-k} {(-1)^m\over m!}}$$

Now my question to is how does one prove this result? I arrived at this deductively, but that is not proof.

Comment: To clarify:  If I am at A at one step, then at the next step I can be anywhere with equal probability?  Or am I trapped on a graph?

Comment: Yes, anywhere other than in any location that you already were.

Comment: But then this is a version of the classical "Matching Problem" (if I throw n letters randomly into n envelopes then find the probability I got exactly k right).  Here's a reference:  http://www.randomservices.org/random/urn/Matching.html

Comment: Never heard of the problem, but it seems like its exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.